# conversion of a varchar to a smalldatetime results in an out-of-range value

Tags: vb.net, smalldatetime

The code:

```
strSql = "insert into table2 (transactiondate) values ('" & transactiondate & "')"
```

seems to be giving me the runtime error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

In the code, strSql is a String object and transactiondate is a Date object.
In the SQL database however, transactiondate is a smalldatetime object.

I've tried changing the smalldatetime to a datetime (in the database) and I've tried transactiondate.toString() but with no success.

How can this be fixed?

Note: I know about the dangers of inline SQL. I am looking for a quick fix solution here and not a discussion about SQL injection.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding single quotes to your insert statement.

```
strSql = "insert into table2 (transactiondate) values ('" & transactiondate & "')"
```

Comment: +1 for just answering the question, but he still needs to fix the SQL injection problem.

Comment: @jello: The OP posted a disclaimer about his awareness of SQL injection. This is a code snippet. You have no idea what cleansing `transactiondate` has already gone through. Every discussion about SQL does NOT need to include SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible answers:

1. You need to encapsulate your string in an apostrophe:

`strSql = "insert into table2 (transactiondate) values ('" & transactiondate & "')"`

2. You're using a date before 1/1/1900 or after 6/6/2079 (the limits of `smalldatetime`)

Answer (score 1):

Smalldatetime can only accept values for years > 1900 and < 2079 as well.  I had a similar error to the one you posted where the solution was to filter out invalid years like such

```
where year(datecolumn) < 2079
```

Comment: Humans create such finite solutions - everything we make has a time limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Use transactiondate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") or your prefered date format. If it remains, change 'sa' user default language, or whatever user you use, to your prefered language.